# How can I get the most specific class of an instance?

Tags: java, types

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

A instA = new A();
A instB = new B();
```

Now as far Java is concerned instB is of type A.

How can I find out what is instB's actual type?

Comment: I guess the point is, why do you want to know. You usually wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `instB.getClass()`. This will return a `Class` object representing `instB`'s runtime type.

Source: [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)

You can also use the following conditional check with `instanceof`:

```
if (instB instanceof B) {
    //then we know it is of type B
}
```

`instanceof` would be the more conventional way, and the conditional will also return true if `instB` is a subclass of `B`.

You may want to further explain your use case, with code examples, to get better discussion.

Answer (score 1):

For **compile-time**, I do not know of any possibility. It is not easy, because it is control flow dependent (looking at the declaration is not sufficient). But when you wrote the declaration, you decided that you only need the class-A-interface/behavior of instB.

For **run-time**, you can use `getClass()`, `instanceof`, as Kublai suggested. But again, you should not need it in most of the cases: With a good design of your classes, you can let dynamic dispatch make the case distinctions.

Comment: Ah, didn't consider the OP might mean at compile time. +1 for that and the design bit.